# last-child and first-child selectors are not working

Tags: css, pseudo-class, css-selectors

I am building a navbar. This is what I want;

change the `background-color` on the link when hoover over it.
first and last link background should have round corners.

The problem is that either all links get rounded corner or none does!

CSS

```
   nav {
       width:100%;
       line-height:2;
   }
   nav ul {
       list-style:none;
   }
   nav li a {
       text-decoration:none;
       color:white;
       float:left;
       width:90px;
       display:block;
       background-color:blue;
       padding-left:10px;
   }
   nav li a:first-child {
       border-radius:5px;
   }
   nav li a:last-child {
       border-radius:5px;
   }
   nav li a:hover {
       color:blue;
       background-color:white;
   }
```

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Hem</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">om oss</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">hitta hit</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakta</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/mkDWj/2/

**You should trigger the `a` within the first and last `li`**, not the first and last `a` within an `li` element, because all `li` only have one `a` (which is automatically its own first and last.

You other issue was that **you were assigning all borders to have the same radius**, when you just want the edge borders to have a radius value.

CSS

```
nav li:first-child a {
    border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
}
nav li:last-child a {
    border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

For more detailed information on the border-radius attribute check this documentation http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp